# Request for math font family to use with Horley

Tags: xetex, typography, math-fonts

What should be a nice font to be used with [Horley Old Style](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/horley-old-style/) font.

I'm using `xelatex` with `fontspec` and `unicode-math` and based on the pdf properties I suppose that CM is being used for math fonts.

So, is there some other math font more recommendable?

Here is an example from the text (and just now I observed the ugly prime for `g'`).

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried stix? Not sure if it matches, but at least it is darker

Comment: @daleif, I never used it. Should I replace `unicode-math` by what?

Comment: `\usepackage{stix}` destroyed a lot of symbols.

Comment: Loading order matter. It is probably also a good idea if you provide a full minimal example for others to test.

Comment: @daleif, thanks. The problem to create a mwe is the font file. I would have to share it. Let me think what can I do.

Comment: The main font is not really relevant if we are just going to test stix for math. But we still need an mwe

Comment: @daleif, while trying to produce the MWE I discovered that the `no-math` option to `fontspec` solved the problem with `stix`. Does it make sense? Looks right now.